# where is the 4th taxonomy terms? taxonomy terms is disaapearing in the loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I am listing custom taxonomy names. The list is displaying and the table 
structure is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td>Name 3</td>
        <td>Name 4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
    .....
</table>
```

The fourth name doesn't display, skipping to to the 5th. If I don't use second loop all taxonomies listing here is the my code:

```
<?php 
    // no default values. using these as examples
    $i          = 0;
    $taxonomies = array( 'urun-kategorileri' );
    $args       = array(
        'orderby'   => 'menu-order',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    ); 
    $tax_terms  = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );

    echo '<table class="table table-hover"><tr>';  

    foreach( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) { {
        $i++;
        if( $i <= 4 ) {
            echo '<td><a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $tax_term, $taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Profilleri Görüntüle %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name . '</a></td>';
            echo ("\n"); 
        }
        else {       
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $i = 0;
        }
    } }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that the 4th taxonomy is populated? If not, you need to set `'hide_empty' => false,` in your `$args`.

Comment: if i set 5 
does'nt display 5th category name
skipping last data 
(all data is populated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skip to the else part in after the 4th run of your foreach. Put the `$i++` at the end of the loop and your fine.

```
foreach( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
    if( $i <= 4 ) {
        echo '<td><a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $tax_term, $taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Profilleri Görüntüle %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name . '</a></td>';
        echo ("\n"); 
    } else {       
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved
i changed for each loop

```
<?php 

    $taxonomies = array( 
        'urun-kategorileri',
    );

    $args = array(
        'orderby'                => 'menu-order',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
    ); 

    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

    echo '<table class="table table-hover"><tr>';  

    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {

        echo '<td><a   href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Profilleri Görüntüle %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></td>';
        echo ("\n"); 

        $counter++;
        if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Properly formt your code please, it is quite messy